# Is checkpointing necessary in spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, checkpointing

I have noticed that spark streaming examples also have code for checkpointing. My question is how important is that checkpointing. If its there for fault tolerance, how often do faults happen in such streaming applications?

Comment: How important is checkpointing depend only on your requirements and business logic. If you want to perform stateful operations are you cannot accept data loss it is obligatory otherwise it optional. If you have a few nodes failures are highly unlikely (it doesn't mean you shouldn't prepare for one), if you have thousand you can expect failures on daily basis. And there software issues on top of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on your use case. For suppose if you are running a streaming job, which just reads data from Kafka and counts the number of records. What would you do if your application crashes after a year or so?

- If you don't have a backup/checkpoint, you will have to recompute all the previous one years worth data so you can resume counting.
- If you have a backup/checkpoint, you can simply read the checkpoint data and resume instantly.

Or if all you are just doing is having a streaming application which just  **Reads-Messages-From-Kafka >>> Tranform >>> Insert-to-a-Database**, I need not worry about my application crashing. Even if it's crashed, i can simply resume my application without loss of data.

Note: Check-pointing is a process which stores the current state of a spark application.

Coming to the frequency of fault tolerance, you can almost never predict an outage. In companies,

- There might be power outage
- regular maintainance/upgrading of cluster

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases:

1. You are doing stateful operations, such as updateStateByKey, then
   you **must use** checkpointing - every state is saved. Without setting
   checkpoint directory, an exception will be thrown.
2. You are doing only windowed operations - then yes, you can disable checkpointing. However I strongly recommend setting checkpoint directory.

When driver is killed, then you'll loose all your data and progress information. Checkpointing helps you to recover applications from such situations.

Is a failure a normal situation? Of course! Imagine that you've got large cluster, many machines, many components in these machines. If one of these components fails, then your application will also fail. When connection to driver is lost -  your application fails. With checkpoiting you can just run application again and it will recover state.